# 'goog:chromeOptions' vs chromeOptions in Protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

It seems at some point chromeOptions was replaced by 'goog:ChromeOptions'.  Does anyone have an idea on when this was changed?  I've found very little documentation on it.

I was running some tests against the Selenium grid version: elgalu/selenium:3.141.59-p41 which uses Chrome 81 and Selenium  3.141.59 and noticed w3c flag was not not being honored until I changed the config to use 'goog:ChromeOptions' instead.

Comment: This is news to me. I use protractor every day all day and I'm still using `chromeOptions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been changed since [ChromeDriver v2.31](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.31/notes.txt).

Because this must be aligned with the [W3C specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#protocol-extensions).

Excerpt:

> Remote ends may also introduce extension capabilities that are extra
> capabilities used to provide configuration or fulfill other
> vendor-specific needs. Extension capabilities’ key must contain a ":"
> (colon) character, denoting an implementation-specific namespace. The
> value can be arbitrary JSON types.
>
> As with extension commands, it is suggested that the key used to
> denote the extension capability namespace is based on the vendor
> keywords listed in [CSS21] and precedes the first ":" character in the
> string.